# Can't make changes in my production Rails project using Capistrano,Puma,Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, nginx, production

i can't make changes in my production Rails project using Capistrano,Puma,Nginx.
I was commited into git and use 'cap production deploy' , after restart the server with 'sudo service nginx restart'. My changes don't apply.

deploy.rb

```
    lock '3.5.0'

set :repo_url, '...'
set :scm, :git
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

set :user, 'deployer'
set :application, 'MyApp'
set :rails_env, 'production'
server '...', user: "#{fetch(:user)}", roles: %w{app db web}, primary: true
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :pty, true
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/puma.rb')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')

set :config_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/config/puma.rb"

namespace :git do
  desc 'Deploy'
  task :deploy do
    ask(:message, "Commit message?")
    run_locally do
      execute "git add -A"
      execute "git commit -m '#{fetch(:message)}'"
      execute "git push"
    end
  end
end

namespace :deploy do
  before 'check:linked_files', 'config:push'
  before 'check:linked_files', 'puma:config'
  before 'check:linked_files', 'puma:nginx_config'
  before 'deploy:migrate', 'deploy:db:create'
  after 'puma:smart_restart', 'nginx:restart'
end
```

Comment: You don't restart the nginx server, not unless you make changes to your server. For application reload use `sudo service puma reload` or `sudo service puma restart` depending on your puma configuration.

Comment: When i use 'sudo service puma reload NameApp' consol tell me - "reload: Env must be KEY=VALUE pairs" . When 'sudo service puma restart app=/home/deployer/apps/NameApp/current' terminal write Stop/Start and nothink change...anyway dont uploads files. Sorry for my english :D

Comment: My guess is that you don't have an upstart puma configuration file. In which case, you probably have to execute this: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb` don't forget to `cd` in your app directory . `cd /home/deployer/apps/MyApp`

Comment: got error "bundler: failed to load command: puma (/home/deployer/apps/NameApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma)
RuntimeError: There is already a server bound to: /home/deployer/apps/nNameApp/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"

Comment: It means that your server ( puma ) is already running. You need to stop it and start it again.

To stop puma you need to kill all it's workers:
`
$ kill -s SIGTERM `cat home/deployer/apps/MyApp/tmp/pids/puma.pid`

$ rm -f home/deployer/apps/MyApp/tmp/pids/puma.pid

$ rm -f home/deployer/apps/MyApp/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
`
and then start it again with the previous command.